# How can I transform pasted HTML code to plain text inside contentedtiable div excluding special HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been struggling with my chat for a while now. My biggest problem is unfortunately still the messages input, which is made with a `contenteditable div`.

Unfortunately, I have the problem that when pasting code, it gets inserted as code instead of text in the input which often destroys the input (e.g. styles of the code gets applied). I have tried to find a solution several times, but I am still not satisfied with the situation. Therefore I tried to work slowly on the matter and developed the following code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#input").on("paste", function (e) {
        let clipboardData, pastedData;

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData("text");
        pastedData = pastedData.replace(/\t/g, "    ");
        pastedData = pastedData.replace(/<\s*([^\s>]+)(?:(?!\bclass="emoji")[^>])*>(.*?)(?:<\/\1>)|<\s*([^\s>]+)(?:(?!\bclass="emoji")[^>])*\/>/g, "$2");

        $("#input").html($("#input").html() + pastedData);
        placeCaretAtEnd($("#input")[0]);
    });
});

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();

    if (typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined" && typeof document.createRange !== "undefined") {
        let range = document.createRange();

        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);

        let sel = window.getSelection();

        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange !== "undefined") {
        let textRange = document.body.createTextRange();

        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.emoji {
  font-family: -apple-system, Segoe UI, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoj, system-ui;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
```

Since I built my chat like WhatsApp Web, I also have emojis which are in a wrapper object. This object should not be replaced in the input when pasting it, which I could already achieve with the code above. As soon as I insert the following code, it will be inserted as code and not as text:

```
<span class="emoji" contenteditable="false"></span>
```

But if I insert some code now, the HTML gets removed instead of pasted as plain text:

```html
This element shows you how it works <span class="emoji" contenteditable="false"></span> <div class="insert-me-as-text">I need to be a text</div>
```

So the code becomes:

```html
This element shows you how it works  I need to be a text
```

But should look like this in the end:

[image]
[image]

And also pressing `Ctrl + Z` needs to work again.

Comment: Just add the text by using `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: @Teemu In this case my wrapper for the emoji get's not added as html but this is important as I wrote above. And also Ctrl + Z still doesn't work using .text()

Comment: If I copy the text containing the emoji from your post, and paste it to a content editable div, without intefering the event, all is pasted as intended.

Comment: Nope. It's not because my emoji wrapper element is not interpreted as HTML but this is the only element that needs to be real HTML inside my contenteditable div as I wrote above.

Comment: Please re-read my comment ...

Comment: @Mr.Jo  What is the purpose of the regex?

Comment: @User863 I've tried to convert the HTML to plain text inside my contenteditable div but it ended up removing the HTML instead transform it to plain text inside the contenteditable

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `.insert-me-as-text` element with the encoded HTML

```
$('<div>').text('<div>...</div>').html() // encodes HTML as string
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#input").on("paste", function(e) {
    let clipboardData, pastedData;

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData("text");
    pastedData = pastedData.replace(/\t/g, "    ");
    
    let $wrap = $('<div/>').html(pastedData);    
    $wrap.find('.insert-me-as-text').replaceWith(function() {
      return $('<div>').text(this.outerHTML).html()
    })

    $("#input").html($("#input").html() + $wrap.html());
    placeCaretAtEnd($("#input")[0]);
  });
});

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();

  if (typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined" && typeof document.createRange !== "undefined") {
    let range = document.createRange();

    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);

    let sel = window.getSelection();

    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange !== "undefined") {
    let textRange = document.body.createTextRange();

    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.select();
  }
}
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.emoji {
  font-family: -apple-system, Segoe UI, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoj, system-ui;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect. This is near my needs. Does it work the other way around, too? Because the emoji should always be preserved, but if someone writes any HTML code now, unfortunately I don't know the class. I think it would make more sense this way around, don't it?

Comment: Yes you can replace all other tags with text except `.emoji` using `not()`

Comment: Sadly `Crtl + Z` to reverse the post is still not working